# How to toggle portrait / landsape screen orientation with launchable command?

Tags: auto-rotation

I would like to get screen rotation under manual control.

```
Action A: set portrait mode
Action B: set landscape mode
```

Both actions with immediate effect, no menu, no confirmation, etc.

I would like to have these commands reachable as regular **launchable app** so I can add them into customizable actions in other apps, i.e. to on-screen drawer (Jina), as Bixby/Google voice command, Bixby button action etc.

Apps I reviewed put such rotation commands into toggle buttons area or to a widget. So they are not launchable on their own. Any idea how to get commands A and B (or one which toggles A/B) available as app?

The device is not rooted.

Comment: You should consider using automation apps. Rotation commands: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864385/changing-android-device-orientation-with-adb

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio – that's also a good idea, if they can accomplish the above. Any specific pointers where to look? If you have an idea how to reach the same effect (possibility of using hardware button, voice command or standalone app icon) with their assistance, post it as an answer, I'll be happy to evaluate it. Or if I can make those adb shell commands launchable in the device, let me know.

Comment: You are looking for this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.appfactory (requires Tasker app installed).